# EF Core, execute on SQL server order by int cast from string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to find the latest generated item in a SQL table.
Unfortunately for legacy reasons I cannot sort by any other column but a string column (`RawValue`).
On top of that I cannot sort on this column as **string** but I need to parse it as **Integer**.

```
MyEntity myEntity = await _dbContext.MyEntity
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Where(...) // irrelevant
  .OrderByDescending(n => int.Parse(n.RawValue)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Entity Framework generated these warnings which evolve all around the above statement.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning" :: The LINQ expression 'orderby Parse([sn].RawValue) desc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning"  :: The LINQ expression 'FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

How can you execute that on the server side with entity framework?

**Model**

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    // ctors..

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string RawValue { get; private set; }

     // more irrelevant properties..
}
```

**Version information**
dotnetcoreapp2.2
EF Core is not directly referenced, but included in `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

**Solution**
I just confirmed that `Convert.ToInt32(string)` does what `int.Parse(string)` does not. It generates an `ORDER BY CONVERT(int, column) ..` SQL statement.

Comment: Clarify what the model is.

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of certain versions of Core where they do not translate certain Linq functions to SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237492/ef-core-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally

Comment: Also doing a `Take(1)` before a `FirstOrDefault` is kinda pointless.

Comment: Does it also process client side if you `OrderByDescending(n => n.RawValue.PadLeft(10,' '))` ? (Just curious whether EF can translate pad left to be a server side op or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the solution is to use

```
Convert.ToInt32
```

Because Int.parse does not have an implementation in the version you are using.