# Finding common items is evaluated locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

Using Entity Framework Core 2.2 I have the following query:

```
IQueryable<User> users = _context.Users.AsNoTracking();

User user = await users
  .Include(x => x.UserSkills)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.Skill)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1);

var userSkills = user.UserSkills.ToList();

IQueryable<Lesson> lessons = _context.Lessons.AsNoTracking();

var test = lessons
  .Where(x => x.IsEnabled)
  .Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y => userSkills.Any(z => y.SkillId == z.SkillId))) 
  .ToList();
```

I am looking to get User Skills contains all Lesson Skills.

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 
'Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: 
The LINQ expression 'where ([y].SkillId == [z].SkillId)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.
```

How to change the query to solve this problem?

**Update**

I need to extend this query with an extra option (`y.SkillLevelId <= z.SkillLevelId`):

```
var test = lessons
  .Where(x => x.IsEnabled)
  .Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y => userSkills.Any(z => 
     y.SkillId == z.SkillId 
     && 
     y.SkillLevelId <= z.SkillLevelId))) 
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core could not be translated and will be evaluated locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237492/ef-core-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally)

Comment: No. The error "could not be translated and will be evaluated locally" is a generic error emitted every time the Linq query cannot be converted to SQL. The question you posted has a different query than mine. The error might be the same but what lead to the error is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userSkills` is in-memory collection, and from my experience with EF6 and EF Core so far I can say that the only reliable translatable construct with in-memory collections is `Enumerable.Contains` method on primitive type in-memory collection.

So the following solves the problem is question.

First (should be outside the query expression tree):

```
var userSkillIds = user.UserSkills.Select(x => x.SkillId);
```

Then instead of

```
.Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y => userSkills.Any(z => y.SkillId == z.SkillId)))
```

use the equivalent (but translatable):

```
.Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y => userSkillIds.Contains(y.SkillId)))
```

**Update:** If you can't use `Contains`, the options you have until EF Core starts supporting it are (1) [EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin](https://github.com/neisbut/EntityFramework.MemoryJoin) package (I personally haven't tested it, but the idea is interesting), (2) manually building `Or` based predicate with `Expression` class (hard and works for small memory collections) and (3) replace the memory collection with real `IQueryable<>`, for instance

```
var userSkills = users
    .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.UserSkills);
```

and use the original query.

Comment: I am using `var userSkills = user.UserSkills.ToList();` making userSkills a Memory Collection as a why to try to solve this ... I can also use user.UserSkills in the query but I also get the exception.

Comment: I know you are making memory collection of `UserSkill` objects. And that's the problem, because the query construct using it does not translate to SQL. While selecting just Ids and using `Contains` works. What's the problem with the suggested solution, have you tried it? Because I did before posting and it worked for me (EF Core 2.2.6).

Comment: Sorry, there is a problem with your answer due to lack of information from me. If you check the update I just added I also need to compare another property: SkillLevel. So contains won't work ... I didn't post this initially because I wanted to simplify the question and wasn't expecting that omission to affect the answer. Sorry.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I see. Unfortunately that is very important detail because anything except Contains does not work with memory collections.